# GDScript String format with an array

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm learning Godot and GDScript as an absolute beginer. For that I follow a course where the instructor make a simple code to format a string with values contained in an array. Here is his code :

[image: Tutorial code]

But when I write the exact same code I have the following error "unsupported format character in operator '%'"

[image: My code]

Can someone explain me what's wrong ? The only difference I can see is that the tutorial was writtenn on Godot 3.1 and I'm on 3.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the second format specifier in `story`. Should be:

...`ate %s flavoured`...

What you're doing is called String Interpolation. As a reminder, all of the `%` inside your string need to have a specifier next to them. `%s` works for now, because you're embedding strings.

The documentation on the other specifiers for future reference: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_format_string.html#format-specifiers